# Local variable is redundant JetBrains IDEs (e.g. IntelliJ IDEA)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

```
public static double getAmount(){
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("random text");
    double amount;
    return (amount = reader.nextDouble());
}
```

IntelliJ gives me this warning on the above code:

> Local variable 'amount' is redundant

Why?

Comment: Side note: Please don't call methods that do complex things like IO  `getSomeName()` - due to the JavaBeans convention we are trained to expect methods with such names to be cheap (and usually side-effect-free) accessors to fields. (Same applies to `isSomething()` and `hasSomething()`) - a name like `readSomeName()` would be preferrable. Don't surprise other programmers (including your future self).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Any variable declared inside a method body (between { and }) will be deleted (garbage collection) at the end of that method. *(unless you asign it to something which is NOT created in the method body)*

You're creating the variable "amount" when you run:

```
 double amount;
```

At this point you've created the variable but never assigned a value to it.
The first time you use this variable is in your return statement:

```
return (amount = reader.nextDouble());
```

What you should've done is either assign the variable on the same line as the declaration:

```
public static double getAmount(){
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("random text");
    double amount  = reader.nextDouble();
    return amount;
}
```

Or, better still, don't use the variable at all (although it may improve code readability, in which case a valid point could be made to keep it):

```
public static double getAmount(){
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("random text");

        return reader.nextDouble();
    }
```

**Why is Intellij warning me?**
Intellij is just telling you that in the end your variable isn't being used (it isn't) so it's safe to remove the variable declaration.

Intellij should however also provide you with a solution like I just did if you hover over the little lightbulb which appears at the start of your line of code.
An example:
[image]

Comment: Sometimes leaving the variable makes things easier to debug, but to each their own

Answer (score 2):

It's telling you that you can simply return `reader.nextDouble()` and that you don't need the variable `amount` for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Because you aren't doing anything with it. The code could be simplified to:

```
public static double getAmount(){
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("random text");
    return reader.nextDouble();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try turning Inspection Mode off for redundant local variables. Or you can just simply do :

```
return reader.nextDouble();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just do

```
 return reader.nextDouble();
```

That variable declaration and assignment are taking up memory.

Comment: Or maybe not. Depends on what the Just in Time compiler does with it.